# Error connecting to Google servers running Gemini AI in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I came to run Gemini AI in Jupyter Notebook in Google Colab according to the Google guide, but I encountered an error in the list modules step: (I don't have a Google Cloud account and Colab Pro)

```
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /v1beta/models?pageSize=50&%24alt=json%3Benum-encoding%3Dint (127.0.0.1) 3290.39ms

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InternalServerError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-20-77709e92acfe> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for m in genai.list_models():
      2   if 'generateContent' in m.supported_generation_methods:
      3     print(m.name)

7 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/model_service/transports/rest.py in __call__(self, request, retry, timeout, metadata)
    826             # subclass.
    827             if response.status_code >= 400:
--> 828                 raise core_exceptions.from_http_response(response)
    829 
    830             # Return the response

InternalServerError: 500 GET http://localhost:38257/v1beta/models?pageSize=50&%24alt=json%3Benum-encoding%3Dint: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

First, I open Google Colab with this [Gemini guide](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/python_quickstart)

Then I opened Google Colab and entered all the commands one by one received the API key from vertex ai placed it here and put the `gemini` value in `GOOGLE_API_KEY`

[apikey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36nSA.png)

and I reached the List models stage and encountered the mentioned error.